# How to make a web-scraper extension automatic instead of event-based

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, automation

I currently have a Google chrome extension which scrapes the text content of an active tab when a button is clicked and opens it in a new window. I'd like for the extension to automatically scrape the text instead of relying on the button being pressed, but not sure how to do this as I am still new to web development.

Currently this is the javascript code for the button which then calls the scrapeTextFromPage function.

```
let scrapePage = document.getElementById("scrapePage");

scrapePage.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    //Get current active tab
    let [tab]= await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});

    //execute script to scrap text on page
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        func: scrapeTextFromPage,
    });
})
```

EDIT: Fixed by using this

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
// Check if the tab status is 'complete' (page loaded) and it's active in the current window
if (changeInfo.status === "complete" && tab.active) {
    // Execute script to scrape text on page
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId },
        function: scrapeTextFromPage,
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Remove scrapePage.addEventListener("click", and just call the function like this: `(async () => { /*your code here*/ })()`

Comment: I managed to fix it by using chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {}  thanks for your help!